# Любой не всякий

Tags: значение-слова

*Любой* (зрим в корень) должно означать не "всякий-разный-встречный-поперечный", *излюбленный, избранный*. Но употребляется именно в первом значении.

Помогите разъяснить недоумение. Спасибо.

Comment: На это вопрос отвечали тут:http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/4888/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: Иногда, едва начинаешь набирать вопрос, высыпаются ссылки на аналогичные вопросы, где уже есть все нужные ответы. А иногда почему-то нет.(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понять связь *лЮбого* с *любЫм* поможет статья в Словаре 1847 :

> ЛюбЫй ... Даваемый на выборъ; выбираемый по желанiю; нравящiйся. *Возьмите любой товаръ. Он нам любъ.*

Comment: Но сейчас-то существует, пусть пока и не зафиксированное в словарях, наречие "по-любому" со значением "во всех случаях", "при любом раскладе".
Получается, что значение плавно перетекло в прямо противоположное, из "самый желанный" в "какой попало"... Вот что странно.